# Grant access to project for all users of different project

Tags: azure-devops

I have in Azure Devops one project with a lot of developer teams. Our Cloud Platform team uses a different project to create artifacts with ARM templates as result of a build pipeline.

How do I grant access to these artifacts for all my developers at group level? At the second project I can create a new group with `View project-level information` permissions. But I can only add users, not groups from that project.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: it would be much easier for people to understand and reply if you could attach either some code that you tried - or perhaps a screen shot of what you are trying to do and want to achieve

Comment: @BasJanssen71 Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

When you add other project groups to the newly created group, do you receive the following error message?

[image]

If so, we can make clear from the error message that this is by design, auzre devops does not support adding groups of different projects to the group.

If you want to add a group as a member to the group you created, then the added group needs to be **organization-level**. Only organization-level groups can be added to project-level groups.

Comment: Hi Hugh Lin , many thanks for your answer ! It's my first time at Stackoverflow :-)  Thats true , I've seen that error message. I just tested it an can add a newly created group at organization level to my group at project level. Any idea why I can not add a build in group like 'Project Collection Valid Users' ??

Comment: @BasJanssen71 Does `Project Collection Valid Users` group refer to permission group? If so, builds cannot be added to the permission group, only users can be added.